# How can I disable phpLDAPadmin without uninstalling it?

Tags: apache-httpd, ldap, phpmyadmin

I installed phpLDAPadmin and it works via http://.../phpldapadmin

Is there any good way to disable phpLDAPadmin without uninstalling it and later I can turn it on only when I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way phpmyadmin is configured with apache is through an apache `alias` directive, if you comment that directive out - it should disable  phpmyadmin.

To find the alias you can grep for phpmyadmin in apaches config directory, i.e.

```
grep -inR "phpmyadmin" /apache/config/directory
```

for me that gave the result

```
...
./conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf|3| Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
...
```

From there you can just open the file and comment out the line.

so you want to take this line

```
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

and make it look like this

```
# Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

That should prevent apache from responding to requests for phpmyadmin.  (assuming its setup as an alias in the first place)